# Dubious purpose of the same origin policy

Tags: javascript, web-services, security, http, web

As I read, the same origin policy is about preventing scripts with origin in (evil) domain A to make requests to (good) domain B - in other words cross-site  request forgery.

Playing around a bit I learned about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`  header and  `CORS` which, as I somehow understand, allows to specify server from the good domain B that the domain A is an allowed origin (therefore not evil) . If this header is not present in the cross-domain response, the browser will not to read anything from it, but it has already made request anyway.

Now, I am somehow missing the point here. If domain B has a web services API and the cookie authentication with the user being logged in, basically any operation can be performed on the poor user's behalf by the evil origin A, just the attacker won't see the response.

What am I missing here? Where is my reasoning faulty?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS - Start reading from Preflighted requests and continue reading Requests with credentials.

Comment: A whole domain doesn't have to be CORS enabled, only the access points they want and are prepared to protect. Unsuspecting domains are left alone

Comment: @Bjorn From that link I understand that some POST requests with credentials will be done without being preflighted so API calls with implications still can be done.

Answer (score 1):

> As I read, the same origin policy is about preventing scripts with origin in (evil) domain A to make requests to (good) domain B - in other words cross-site request forgery.

The Same Origin Policy prevents a mismatched domain, port or protocol combination *reading* from another origin. It says nothing about restricting requests *from being made in the first place*.

e.g.

- `http://www.example.com` cannot read anything on `http://www.example.edu`
- `https://www.example.com` cannot read anything on `http://www.example.com` (except cookies, as the Same Origin Policy for cookies is different)
- `http://www.example.com:8080` cannot read anything on `http://www.example.com`

The Same Origin Policy does not prevent a request being *made* to another domain. It is only the response that is read only. So...

- `http://www.example.com` could POST data to `http://www.example.edu` via AJAX or form (even with credentials if 3rd party cookies are enabled in the browser)
- `http://www.example.com` could POST data to `https://www.example.com` via AJAX or form
- As far as the Same Origin Policy is concerned, `https://www.example.com` could POST data to `http://www.example.com` although the browser will more than likely either block the request or warn the user as HTTP content is accessed over a HTTPS page. Definitely when via AJAX, via form will depend on the browser and settings
- `http://www.example.com` could load an image from `http://www.example.edu`, however the image data will not be available via scripting

So CORS does not relax the security of what was already possible, it allows a domain to opt into CORS and allows another domain to read responses from it.

Answer (score 0):

CORS doesn't *prevent* anything that was allowed before CORS was invented. It only specifies a way for sites to *allow* requests that were previously always denied.

One site could always cause a user agent to make requests to other sites, since the beginning of the Web. Just think hotlinked images.

Typically, it's not correct for a site to authorize an action just based on a cookie, because, as you point out, any site can make requests using other sites' cookies.

A site will usually require that the request contain something other than the cookie. It might, for example, look for a CSRF token that must be read from a previous response. As site B, you'd need use CORS to obtain this token.